What is the oldest open math problem outside of number theory?
The question of "What is the oldest open problem in mathematics?" comes up from time to time, and there seems to be consensus that the answer is "Are there any odd perfect numbers?".
There are many other old open problems in number theory. See the prior mathoverflow question on that question for some examples.
What I'm interested to know here is:

What is the oldest (or some candidates for the oldest) open math problem clearly outside of number theory?

EDIT: The same question was asked two years ago on the History of Science and Mathematics StackExchange, but did not elicit an accepted answer.
This is a soft question, so I do not want to apply too rigid of 'rules'. But a few guidelines are:

I can't formally define what is number theory. Certainly I want to
exclude anything to do with primes, factorizations, irrationality,
transcendentality, constructibility, rational/integral solutions to
equations, etc.
There should be a clear record of the problem being formulated as a conjecture or question (as opposed to "so-and-so surely would have considered X after studying y".)


see https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/14748/1697

@CarloBeenakker: thanks for the link (which I was not aware of)! That said, its hard to extract even a candidate from the discussion there that isn't (1) solved, (2) outside the given definition of number theory, or (3) whose formulation date is undisputed.

It does seem surprisingly hard to locate problems predating 1900. Once you get to 1900 you can sort through Hilbert's problem list. I've seen multiple sources say Navier-Stokes predates this, but I don't know enough about the problem or its history to assess how fair it is to date, say, the Clay formulations back that far.

I’m voting to close this question because it has already been asked on hsm.se, where it is more on-topic

@FedericoPoloni: I think that's a fair vote, and I'll happily defer to our governance processes. To be a bit pedantic, though, that question asked for problems greater than 200 years old and essentially didn't find one. Here we certainly should be able to a identify a problem of maximum age here (which people will likely update over time if/when they stumble on better examples).

@MarkLewko True, but still I think that this question belongs on [hsm.se].

@FedericoPoloni I am not sure. I expect that there exist many mathematicians who can answer questions like this and who are active rather on MO than on HSM

The oldest still-open problem in set theory post-dates Hilbert's list, so it's not the answer to this question. But if you're interested, here's a link to a blog post (written by Asaf Karagila, whom you may recognize from MO) explaining the problem and some of its history: https://karagila.org/2014/on-the-partition-principle/

In 1887, Kelvin asked the question for three-dimensional space: how can space be partitioned into cells of equal volume with the least area of surface between them: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weaire%E2%80%93Phelan_structure#The_Kelvin_conjecture

@FedorPetrov I don't find this a convincing argument, personally. There are many people who would love their questions to be seen by a community of professional mathematicians, but this does not make their questions automatically on-topic here. But I know my opinion is not shared by everyone; this has been discussed on https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4566/ and https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/394/ .

@FedericoPoloni if mathematicians are not against to see such questions, then why not? History of mathematics is intimately related to mathematical research: every research paper has historical part; the high interest to history of mathematics is much more natural for mathematicians then to anybody else, and it can teach us a lot. The same concerns philosophy of mathematics, teaching mathematics and other things mathematicians have a natural interest in.

@FedorPetrov In the abstract I agree with you, but the existing HSM question is morally speaking a duplicate of this question, and only technically speaking not a duplicate because HSM and MO are technically different sites. I don't see that anything is gained by taking advantage of this loophole to post a duplicate here on MO. Any good answers can be appended to the existing HSM question.

@TimothyChow If it is properly answered on HSM, then it can be closed as a duplicate, but I have doubts about this. Many questions from Math.se are duplicated here if they do not get an answer there, why should it be different with HSM?

@TimothyChow 1882 is pretty good but I think it ought to be possible to find something earlier. I have read that Riemann first introduced Riemannian manifolds, although not with modern standards of rigor, in 1854. Surely the problem of classifying Riemannian manifolds must have been asked shortly thereafter--to me it seems the problem suggests itself as soon as you see the definition. Of course the problem of classifying manifolds (incl. Riemannian manifolds) in various families is a huge problem, and actively worked on today.

@user509184 Well, Mark Lewko has specifically excluded "so-and-so surely would have considered X after studying Y".

@FedorPetrov Again I think you make a good point in the abstract, but my feeling is that for this particular question, the chances of getting a much better answer on MO are not very high. It's a soft question, and the nature of the question is more suited to HSM than MO. But, I suppose the community might feel differently and vote to reopen.

Gauss was tabulating knots in 1794. I'm not familiar with his notebooks, but I wonder if he explicitly asked about the efficiency of knot recognition methods?

Are there any problems about Latin squares / finite projective planes going back to Euler that are still open?

I don't have a 200 year old candidate but I can offer a 150 year old one (from Maxwell's "Treatise on Electricity and Magnetism" written in 1873).
You are allowed to put $n$ electric point charges in $\mathbb R^3$ in any way you want. What is the maximal number of equilibrium points of the resulting electric field as a function of $n$? (there are several variation of that: both positive and negative charges are allowed, only positive charges are allowed, all charges must be unit, you place them in $\mathbb R^d$ with arbitrary $d$, etc., etc.).
As far as I know, in full generality the question still remains open. I learned it from Alexandre Eremenko, who can probably comment more on it.
This was just to set the "trivial lower bound" :-)

It seems (from the paper of Gabrielov, Novikov and Shapiro: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0409009) that Maxwell asserted without proof an upper bound (in fact $(n-1)^2$) on the number of equilibrium points in his treatise, rather than posing it as a question/conjecture. That said, it is a good example particularly given that it is precisely formulated in the original source.

@Mark Lewko: more precisely, they did not prove finiteness, but assuming finiteness, they proved un upper bound. As far as I know, the problem is unsolved even for 3 charges. I've a computer assisted for 3 equal charges, but did not verify that it is correct, and it is not published.

I still have flashbacks about this problem - Boris Shapiro gave me this problem to work on, first year as an undergraduate student. I did not manage to get far :)

Stability of the Solar System ?
(Question often attributed to Newton in Opticks, 1717 or 1730.)
To further specify as requested by Timothy Chow, make it a few ($3\leqslant N\leqslant 8$) planets under pure Newtonian attraction, as in Suzuki, A history of the stability problem in celestial mechanics, from Newton to Laplace (1642–1787) (p. 24):

The other form of the stability question was that the planets themselves, by mutual gravitation alone, might disturb their orbits “until the system wants a reformation,” a point most famously raised by Newton in Optics. Because of the uncertainty of the validity of universal gravitation, this problem could not even be asked until after mid-century, but thereafter, progress was rapid and by 1760, a preliminary answer was obtained by Charles Euler, followed, over the next two decades, by the works of Lagrange and Laplace.

A “clear record of the problem being formulated as a conjecture or question” is in e.g. Laplace (1784):

si l’on n’a égard qu’aux lois de la gravitation universelle, les moyennes distances des corps célestes aux foyers de leurs forces principales sont immuables (…). Mais les excentricités et les inclinaisons sont-elles renfermées constamment dans d’étroites limites? C’est un point important du système du monde qui reste encore à éclaircir.


I was about to suggest this one, but it's a little murky. First, is it a physics question about the actual solar system, or a math question about the equations of Newtonian mechanics? If the latter, what is the question exactly? E.g., Arnold's work on the KAM theorem tells us that there are some solar-system-like systems that are stable. So maybe the question is determining which systems are stable and which aren't. In addition to the article you linked to, this Quanta article is also interesting.

That question, or some version of it, is still open, but it isn't the question Newton asked. This article by Scott Tremaine gives some more information about what the early discussions of the problem looked like.

Suzuki (1996, §1.5 “The Stability Question Raised”) discusses the two versions: “non-gravitational causes”, versus analysis of the purely gravitational problem (p. 24). The latter is the mathematical problem I have in mind, discussed by Laskar.

Right, but precisely how many masses are we including in our mathematical idealization of the solar system? Just the eight planets? Or do we include dwarf planets? How close do the masses, positions, and velocities in our mathematical idealization have to be to the masses of the actual physical objects they're modeling? Arnold's result concerns "solar systems" with parameter values that are many orders of magnitude different from those in our actual solar system. At what point are we asking questions about the space of all possible solar systems rather than "the" solar system?

I see you have edited the question to clarify, but the number of planets is not the only critical parameter; the mass-ratio is also important. See for example this abstract.

However much you narrow or expand the problem, I think it will include boundedness of the elements (semimajor axes etc.), which Laplace (1787, 1795) thought he had proved; whereby (per Suzuki, p. 251): “so far as Laplace is concerned, the stability of this solar system has been assured, and the general problem of a system of planets operating under the inverse square law is of no concern”. (In fact, Laplace only solved what we would call that problem’s linearization.)

A quibble, and a question: was the quote really "Charles Euler", or was it possibly "Chasles, Euler..." ?

Motivated by @paulgarrett's question, I tried to check the original.  As far as I could tell, "the quoted Suzuki" was not named in the post, but I assume it's the same as in the comment, and so edited it in.  (It is indeed "Charles Euler" in the original.  )  Also, for some strange reason, the quotation marks in the quote from Laplace seemed to be backwards (opening quotation marks).  I turned them around, which is hopefully what was intended.

There is actually a bizarre story surrounding the "Charles Euler" paper. Apparently Euler entered a Paris Academy prize competition in his son's name (Carl/Carolus/Charles). Jacobi speculates that this was because he had been teased for winning these competitions so many times. For proof of the true author Jacobi cites the inscription: "The father decided that all the stars in heaven should move."

Wow! Thanks for the info, Loren S. and NM :)

I suggested this candidate in a comment: For which $d$ and $g$ does there exist a curve in $\mathbb{P}^3$ of degree $d$ and genus $g$? In Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, Chapter VI, Section 6, it is indicated that the Steiner Prize was awarded in 1882 to Noether and Halphen for work on this problem and related problems (although if one wants to be pedantic about the earliest date on which the question was formulated explicitly, I don't know when that would be). According to another MO answer, Hartshorne's claim that this problem is open remains true today.
If this particular problem doesn't answer Mark Lewko's question, then there may be similar questions in classical algebraic geometry that do. For comparison, the interpolation problem, of determining when there is a (Brill–Noether) curve of degree $d$ and genus $g$ passing through $n$ general points in $\mathbb{P}^r$, was only recently solved by Larson and Vogt.

Look at the reference I gave https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/14748/old-unsolved-questions-in-mathematics for examples "outside physics" and older than those in this list.

@TimothyChow: do you have any information about the original source of this problem? As an aside, I had never heard of the Steiner Prize. Apparently for some of its existence (which came to an end with WWI) eminent mathematicians of the era (including Dirichlet and Weierstrass) would pose problems, with the idea the prize would go to the best work on the problem. Reportedly these problems frequently went unsolved and the prizes unclaimed. It would be interesting to know if the full statements of these problems survive. See: https://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/mprize-prev.pdf

@MarkLewko I don't think that tracking down the text of the people who offered the prize is going to lead anywhere. A more promising route may be to look at the collected works of Halphen, to see what problems he stated explicitly.

The Navier–Stokes equation was mentioned in a comment so I thought I would give a link to Sylvio R. Bistafa's essay, 200 Years of the Navier-Stokes Equation, which gives some historical information. Briefly, although Navier's work appeared in 1822, the Clay Prize version of the problem is probably not older than the problem fedja suggested, because the early work on the equation implicitly or explicitly assumed laminar flow.

I originally voted to close this MO question as a duplicate of the HSM question, but since the community has decided to reopen the MO question, I edited the HSM question to point here to MO.

The inverse Galois problem is another possible candidate, though it may not be easy to track down the earliest explicit statement of it. Wikipedia claims that it was posed in the early 19th century, but Galois died in 1832 and there does not seem to be any concrete evidence that he explicitly posed the problem. I kind of doubt it was explicitly posed any earlier than 1853, when Kronecker first stated what we now call the Kronecker–Weber theorem. In the other direction, the problem should be dated no later than Hilbert's 1892 Crelle paper, "Uber die Irreducibilitat ganzer rationaler Functionen mit ganzzahligen Coefficienten".

This problem would almost always be considered part of number theory.

@WillSawin Could be, though in my anecdotal experience, number theorists don't seem to be particularly interested in it, while (for example) group theorists like John Thompson are.

Well for example David Zywina has done a lot of work on it.

@WillSawin Thanks for mentioning Zywina; I was unaware of his work but it seems very nice. For what it's worth, when I searched MathSciNet for his name and "inverse Galois" in the title, the hits I got had a primary subject classification of 12 (field theory and polynomials), specifically 12F12 (inverse Galois theory), rather than 11 (number theory).

... and, after all, who gets to decide what is or isn't "number theory"? :)

Number theorists are very much interested in the quantitative variant (how many number fields of given $G$ and discriminant at most $X$ in absolute value), cf Malle's conjecture and work on it.

A long-standing unresolved problem in celestial mechanics is to determine the number / finiteness of relative equilibria in the $n$-body problem, for any choice of positive masses $m_1, \ldots, m_n$. (#6 of Smale's problems.) The $n$-body problem was introduced at least as far back as Newton, but does anyone have a reference for the earliest reference to this specific question?
